# SQL Query Count and Label if first

Tags: sql, count, unique, record

I'm using SQL Server management Studio 2010.

I need my query to populate a column if the record contains the first occurrence of a value.

The table my query returns is huge so I'll just use pretend columns to get my point across. My query currently returns a table that looks like this

```
| ROW | ItemNumber | DateOpen | Status |
|  1  |      10045 | 5/5/2005 |   Open |
|  2  |      10045 | 5/5/2005 |   Open |
|  3  |      10046 | 5/5/2005 |   Open |
|  4  |      10046 | 5/5/2005 |   Open |
|  5  |      10046 | 5/5/2005 |   Open |
```

I've already added the row indicator in to the query thinking it would help identify the first occurrence of an ItemNumber. I need to have a new column that marks an X if the record is the first occurrence.

I have this so far

```
    DECLARE @ItemData Table(itemRow BIGINT, itemNumber BIGINT, DateOpen VARCHAR(15), status VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO @ItemData (itemRow, ItemNumber, DateOpen, Status)
SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Cm_ItemNumber) AS 'ROW'
       ,Cm_ItemNumber                            AS ItemNumber
       ,Dates_DateOpen                           AS DateOpen
       ,St_Status                                AS Status
FROM db_Items
JOIN db_Dates ON Dates_Item = Cm_ItemID
JOIN db_Status ON St_ID = Cm_StatusID
Select * from @ItemData
```

The reason its thrown into a table then selected seperately is because there's actually a union and a lot more stuff in the query and when I realized I needed to do a unique checker and add it to a column, I figured the easiest way would be an "after the fact" type thing and it would go into the     `Select * from @ItemData` portion.

Comment: Is the first occurence based on the row or the date open?

Comment: based on row number. I probably poorly labeled it. the specific row doesn't matter, I just need each item number only labeled once and figured that adding a distinct record via row numbers, that would make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it's along the lines I'd be playing with...
using your existing query as the first of 2 CTEs :

```
With AllData as
(
SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Cm_ItemNumber) AS 'ROW'
       ,Cm_ItemNumber                            AS ItemNumber
       ,Dates_DateOpen                           AS DateOpen
       ,St_Status                                AS Status
FROM db_Items
JOIN db_Dates ON Dates_Item = Cm_ItemID
JOIN db_Status ON St_ID = Cm_StatusID
),
FirstRows as
(
SELECT Min(ROW) as Row, ItemNumber
FROM AllData 
GROUP BY ItemNumber
)
SELECT
  ad.*,
  Case When fr.Row IS NULL then '' else 'X' end as X_Col
FROM AllData ad LEFT JOIN FirstRows fr 
  ON ad.ROW=fr.Row
```

Comment: I would approve your edit to `Case When fr.row IS NULL then` if I could work out how to :) I don't seem to have any Approve or Reject to click!